# java.io.IOException: getNextMsg refill failed

Tags: http, java-me

I am working with http secure connection in j2me. While throwing url it is showing exception as "Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: getNextMsg refill failed". First of all I am not getting the point what is mean by getNextMsg???

Comment: Please, add more info to this question. For example, what protocol are you using?

Comment: This exception occur when I was working with http/1.0

Comment: In your question you wrote "http secure" so I thought it would be https or ssl. What code is executed "While throwing url" ?

Comment: secure url only actually in my code there will be 2 request one with http and another https

Comment: What code is executed "While throwing url" ?